# mysql subquery for like condition and subquery has a where condition

Tags: mysql

I want:

```
1_tag_chain = select tag_chain from tree_node where id = 1
select * from tree_node where tag_chain like (1_tag_chain + "%");
```

I tried:

```
 select t1.id from tree_node as t1 join tree_node as t2 on (t1.tag_chain like (t2.tag_chain + '%') and t2.id = 1);
```

or

```
select * from tree_node where tag_chain like (select tag_chain from tree_node where id = 1 + "%");
```

or

```
select * from tree_node where tag_chain like (select tag_chain + "%" from tree_node where id = 1);
```

they gave only id equals to 1 result.

Besides, I am thinking, would `join` operation results in a very large temporary middle data set?

UPDATE:
I found it may give unexpected result because of the difference of:
`like (91 + "%")`
and
`like ("91%")`

Comment: I think you are trying to use `+` as string concatenation, but that's only for Microsoft SQL Server. In MySQL, use the [CONCAT() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

Comment: @BillKarwin right. I found that at `https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html`. I finally solved it by `select count(id) from tree_node where tag_chain like (select concat(tag_chain, "%") from tree_node where id = 1);`